# Can CSS pseudo-classes be used inside of the :not() pseudo-class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering if its possible to "embed" pseudo-classes inside of each other. I have a hunch that you can't, but I just want to make sure I don't just have syntax wrong.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
p.description { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

Given that style, if you only want that to happen on matches that aren't the LAST p.description, is there anyway to do the following?

```
p.description:not(p.description:last-child)
```

Naturally, I'd have two styles, like so:

```
p.description { margin-bottom: 20px; }
p.description:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

...but that seems wasteful if it can be done in a single line.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes,** to the title of your question:

```
p.description:not(:last-child)
```

**No,** to the CSS example in the body of your question

```
p.description:not(p.description:last-child)
```

[The spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.
>
> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

Comment: Hm, apparently the definition was changed between CSS2 and CSS3. In CSS2, `p.description:first-child` would be considered a simple selector.

Comment: Aside from whether or not it's "reasonable" for `:not()` to take simple selectors only, I think the CSS3 definition of "simple selector" _is_ reasonable, and makes more sense than the CSS2 definition.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had a hunch it was possible but I wasn't sure what the correct syntax was. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `p.description:not(:last-child)`.

Comment: ... because `:not()` can take a simple selector, which the pseudo-class `:last-child` is.

Comment: Sorry, I had already edited the post when you said this. (I wrote a JavaScript library that allows complex selectors in `:not()` so I got a bit confused :P)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in webkit it works fine. I use this for example:

```
.middlenav:not(:nth-last-child(1))
```

Works great.

so `p.description:not(:last-child).`
should too